# Interpretar float como unsigned int

Tags: c

Alguien puede explicar el porque interpretar un float como un entero según entiendo se perderían datos, es un casting C valido?

```
float sqrt7(float x)
{
   unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*) &x;
   i  += 127 << 23;
   i >>= 1; 
   return *(float*) &i;
}
```

Además después se vuelve a castear a float, es la primera vez que veo este tipo de códigos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los números en coma flotante pueden, por un lado, tener decimales, mientras un entero no. Si conviertes un número con decimales a una representación que no admite decimales vas a perder la parte decimal del número, por lo que vas a perder precisión.

```
float num_decimal = 10.5;
int num_entero = (int)num_decimal;
printf("%d",num_entero); // imprime 10
```

Otro problema que puede presentar esta conversión es que el rango de valores admitido por `float` es mucho mayor que el soportado por `int` o `unsigned int`. Forzar una conversión cuando se excede el rango del tipo de destino da como resultado números que no tienen nada que ver... Un número positivo que se convierte en negativo...

Y como nota final, los anterior afecta especialmente a los `unsigned int` ya que todo `float` con valor negativo que se convierta en `unsigned int` dará como resultado un número positivo que poco o nada tendrá que ver con el número original.

Dicho esto:

**¿es malo hacer este tipo de conversiones?**

En absoluto. Lo malo es hacerlas a lo loco y sin tener muy claro que la conversión es segura. En muchas ocasiones te encontrarás con que es inevitable hacer una conversión para comunicar tu programa con una librería... Solo tendrás que garantizar que la conversión no se convierte en algo dañino.

**¿Lo que comento en que afecta al ejemplo?**

Al ejemplo concreto no le afecta absolutamente en nada.

Me explico: el ejemplo realiza una conversión de `float` a `unsigned int` únicamente porque las instrucciones de desplazamiento binario no están disponibles para el tipo `float`.

El código está asumiendo que `unsigned int` y `float` van a ocupar el mismo número de bytes. Para evitar hacer una conversión de datos (que implicaría pérdida de previsión), crea un puntero a `unsigned int` y hace que dicho puntero apunte al float. De esta forma desde el punto de vista del puntero lo que hay almacenado ahí es de tipo `unsigned int`, por lo que las operaciones de desplazamiento binario de activan automáticamente.

Si en vez de un puntero se hiciese una conversión de los datos se producirían los efectos comentados al principio.

Un saludo

Comment: He encontrado que a esto lo llaman type punning https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning y tiene comportamiento indefinido en C

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el comportamiento en este caso viene determinado por el procesador. En el caso de PCs de consumo, hasta donde llego, tanto Intel como AMD tienen un comportamiento similar.

Comment: @cheroky piensa que muchos de los comportamientos indeterminados en C lo son simplemente porque delega en el hardware o en el SO. En este caso, las instrucciones de manipulación de bits son dependientes del procesador. Eso sí, tienes que ser consciente de que correr esa función bajo un procesador que use un formato diferente para trabajar con números en coma flotante (por ejemplo un tamaño diferente para el exponente y/o la mantisa) producirá un resultado diferente.